# Can I restrict the date in the range to be a minimum of one day?

Tags: angular, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

i.e do not permit 12/06/2017 - 12/06/2017

But the date is at least one day.

i.e 12/06/2017 - 12/07/2017

I'm using this https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker

Comment: what do you mean? do you want to **allow** the user to choose a day only within a certain range? or what?

Comment: I want the minimum range to be one day. That is, the start date and end date can not be the same. At a minimum it have to have a day of rank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build any custom validation on top of datepicker
We have a planned feature to include preprocessing of date selection but it will happen later. 
Date range selection could be one day too, air tickets selection for example, both ways in one day for example